# Reset Service can't marshall a jaxb Object without @XmlRootElement

Tags: xml, spring, rest, spring-boot, jaxb

I'm developing a web application and i have a Rest Service that produces a xml.  The header looks like this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{catalogId}",method= RequestMethod.GET,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public @ResponseBody
ResponseEntity<CatalogueType> getCatalog(@PathVariable(value = "catalogId") String catalogId, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
```

The problem is that CatalogueType is a JAXB Object but without @XmlRootElement tag, and for that reason i get HTTP 406 error. I can't modify the return class. How can i make this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's impossible to modify `CatalogueType` just create another class, say `CatalogueTypeResponse` which will have the same structure as `CatalogueType` and add all required annotations.From the first glance this can look like code duplication, but from your explanation is seems like `CatalogueType` is something internal to your controller. But controller itself is usually documented public interface, so returned object should not be affected by possible changes in `CatalogueType`. Thus, this is not a bad practice.

Actually your original issue seems weird to me, it should print XML/JSON representation of POJO without any annotations. Have you added all necessary jars (i.e. Jackson)?